# set the position of a single particle of a particle system that I create

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have this particle system that I create, after I create it I would like all single particles to go to the player, but I don't know how to access and set single particles
 `ParticleSystem e = Instantiate(materialParticle,hitDestro.transform);`

i tried to use particlesystem.particle but i don't know how to set it so it gave me error

I would like to create some "experience" that when a certain object is destroyed the experience appears and goes to the player automatically

experience I would like it to be a particle system

I tried to do it with the answers of other similar questions but it doesn't work for me

Comment: You can do this using a [`ParticleSystemForceField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystemForceField.html) ... basically you simply set it to a certain radius and apply a gravity towards this object (=> your player) then additionally on your player or the particles you simply check for `OnPartileTrigger` and apply your EXP accordingly => This tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ8aKXcnlrI shows and explains all that

Comment: I've seen that tutorial but I can't set the individual particles
(however my game is in 3d even if it doesn't change much)and then I would like the particles always go to the player not only when they are inside the forcefield

Comment: jut make your force field large enough? What do you mean by `I can't set the individual particles` .. you mean you want different types of objects to spawn?

Comment: Il valore del mi dice non può essere null 
int triggeredParticles = e.GetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Enter, elolo);
the only thing is that on the particle system it doesn't let me put the gameobject with the collider, because the particle system is a prefab and the gameobject with the collider is not

Comment: ok now it gives me no errors but it never calls 
for (int i = 0; i < triggeredParticles; i++)
            {
                ParticleSystem.Particle p = elolo[i];
                Debug.Log("yea");
                p.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(e.transform.position, 
                player.transform.position, ref velocity, spee * Time.deltaTime);
                elolo[i] = p;
            }